# C++ SSL connect: message too long

Tags: c++, sockets, ssl, tcp, openssl

I'm developing a application where many clients should connect to a server application and transmit every minute a string with about 300 Bytes. The client's are only a gateway between RS232 and the socket server. The connection between the clients and the server is SSL encrypted with openssl. Both are developed in C++.

The transmission is running 24/7 but it's not critical if some data get lost.

First I tried it with a TCP connection, but I got trouble with it, because the connection break some times. So I decided to connect and disconnect every Minute, when I send the informations (Maybe later I will cache some data and send it not every minute). Because of that I thought it would be better to use a UDP connection with DTLS.

But I have two problems with the UDP connection.

1. ca every 10th string has one missing character. It's not really critical, but isn't it maybe a fault in my code ?
2. If I use "SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations" to verify my client, I sometimes got an error: "SSL connect: message too long".
   I think it should be typically for messages over 64K? But on connect I don't send any data? How can this happen while connecting ?

You think UDP is the right protocol for me? Or should I rather use TCP?

Here are some details from my code:

Server:

```
server_addr.s4.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_addr.s4.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server_addr.s4.sin_port = htons(port);

THREAD_setup();
OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms();
SSL_load_error_strings();
ctx = SSL_CTX_new(DTLSv1_server_method());
SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, "ALL:NULL:eNULL:aNULL");
SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode(ctx, SSL_SESS_CACHE_OFF);

if (!SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, SERVERCERT, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM))
    printf("\nERROR: no certificate found!");

if (!SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, SERVERKEY, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM))
    printf("\nERROR: no private key found!");

if (!SSL_CTX_check_private_key (ctx))
    printf("\nERROR: invalid private key!");

if(!SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, CACERT, NULL))
    cout << "\nERROR: no ca-cert found!\n";

SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER | SSL_VERIFY_CLIENT_ONCE | SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT, dtls_verify_callback);

SSL_CTX_set_read_ahead(ctx, 1);
SSL_CTX_set_cookie_generate_cb(ctx, generate_cookie);
SSL_CTX_set_cookie_verify_cb(ctx, verify_cookie);

fd = socket(server_addr.ss.ss_family, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if (fd < 0) {
    perror("socket");
    exit(-1);
}

setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const void*) &on, (socklen_t) sizeof(on));

bind(fd, (const struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

while (1)
{
        memset(&client_addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage));

        bio = BIO_new_dgram(fd, BIO_NOCLOSE);

        timeout.tv_sec = 5;
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;
        BIO_ctrl(bio, BIO_CTRL_DGRAM_SET_RECV_TIMEOUT, 0, &timeout);

        ssl = SSL_new(ctx);

        SSL_set_bio(ssl, bio, bio);
        SSL_set_options(ssl, SSL_OP_COOKIE_EXCHANGE);

        while (DTLSv1_listen(ssl, &client_addr) <= 0);

        info = (struct pass_info*) malloc (sizeof(struct pass_info));
        memcpy(&info->server_addr, &server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage));
        memcpy(&info->client_addr, &client_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage));
        info->ssl = ssl;

        if (pthread_create( &tid, NULL, connection_handle, info) != 0) {
            perror("pthread_create");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    THREAD_cleanup();
}
```

Client:

```
OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms();
SSL_load_error_strings();
ctx = SSL_CTX_new(DTLSv1_client_method());
SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, "eNULL:!MD5");

if (!SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, CLIENTCERT, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM))
    printf("\nERROR: no certificate found!");

if (!SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, CLIENTKEY, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM))
    printf("\nERROR: no private key found!");

if (!SSL_CTX_check_private_key (ctx))
    printf("\nERROR: invalid private key!");

if(!SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx,CACERT,NULL))
    cout << "\nERROR: cannot load CA Cert file for verification!\n";


SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx,SSL_VERIFY_PEER,NULL);
SSL_CTX_set_read_ahead(ctx, 1);


ssl = SSL_new(ctx);

bio = BIO_new_dgram(fd, BIO_CLOSE);

connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &remote_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

BIO_ctrl(bio, BIO_CTRL_DGRAM_SET_CONNECTED, 0, &remote_addr.ss);

SSL_set_bio(ssl, bio, bio);

if (SSL_connect(ssl) < 0) {
    perror("SSL_connect");
    printf("%s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), buf));
    exit(-1);
}

timeout.tv_sec = 3;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;
BIO_ctrl(bio, BIO_CTRL_DGRAM_SET_RECV_TIMEOUT, 0, &timeout);
```

Comment: The "data too long error" sounds like a variable is uninitialized or something is smashing memory. Or maybe even faulty memory on one of your boards. The other option is, its not SSL/TLS at all; its HTTP but the markup is being interpreted as TLS protocol data. Also see [Error in openssl s_client: “data length is too long”](http://serverfault.com/q/402152/145545) on Server Fault.

Comment: Can you post the exact error string you receive? ERR_error_string() gives error information in a specific format which can help narrow the problem down. Also what version of OpenSSL are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. But I decided to go back to TCP. I have too much data loss with UDP..